# What is meant with "Run make inside the vim directory"

Tags: vim, f#, syntastic

This is a simple and perhaps forehead-slapping obvious question, but I still venture to ask it. It is part of a larger effort to troubleshoot a problem I have with `vim-fsharp` (see [github repo here](https://github.com/fsharp/vim-fsharp)), where I continually get error messages like "Error detected while processing function fsharpbinding#python#OnBufWritePre" and a number of broken pipe errors. I have tried to uninstall and re-install the plugin a few times and with different methods, but none have worked so far, so I'm trying to reconstruct my install process in minutae.

I have also tried to ensure that I have the proper privileges and have run all possible commands with sudo.

My question is now regarding the third point in the installation instruction "Run make inside the vim directory." I'm not sure I understand what the vim directory in this context is. Is it `~/.vim` or `~/.vim/bundle/vim-fsharp`? And does this mean that I do the following (after having ensured that I have both pathogen and syntastic and run `git clone https://github.com/fsharp/vim-fsharp.git`): `cd vim-fsharp && sudo make`?

Comment: When you work in `$HOME` (`~`/) you don't need `sudo`. Run `make` where a `Makefile` exists.

Comment: Ah, ok, this might be where my problem lies, as I seem to be needing to sudo everything I do something in $HOME (else it complains about privileges)..

Comment: Indeed it was a problem with privileges - I had copied ~/.vim from another user I had and hadn't changed ownership

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Run make inside the vim directory.

`make` needs a `Makefile`. Since you are unlikely to have one in `~/.vim/` and there's one in `~/.vim/bundle/vim-fsharp` you must logically do `$ make` in the latter:

```
$ cd ~/.vim/bundle/vim-fsharp
$ make
```

If I read the `Makefile` right you don't need `sudo`.